# Google maps not loading android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google map gets displayed on device when I plug it to my machine and run app from eclipse. But when I run the same code from another machine's eclipse map is not displayed.
It shows "Failed to load map. Could not contact google services. This is probably due to wifi connection or the request is not authorized."

I have all the permission and other manifest tags added correctly with correct API key. This is obvious as it runs from my machine.

Has anyone encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the API key is coupled with your debug keystore, the best way would be to copy this keystore to other machines, which are also used for development. debug.keystore is in .android folder in your user folder.

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer for your problem! You need a new API Key for the new machine you are trying to launch the app from. You'll need the SHA1 fingerprint of the new machine in order to create the new API Key in the API Console.

With the new Android Development Tools you can do this very easily. You no longer need to find the `debug.keystore` and the java bin files to run the previous command line in the command console that generates the SHA1.

To generate the SHA1: Open **ADT**. Go to **Main Menu** Window => **Preferences** => **Android** => **Build**. There you have the **SHA1** and MD5 options. You know what to do now: join the SHA1 with the package of your project: e.g. `SHA1;myandroid.project`.

You have the new Key for the new machine. Update the `manifest.xml` and run the project again. It should work now.

I have just noticed another issue: Be careful when you create your apk file, if you sign it with a keystore you have created, your application map don´t work. I have read that you have to sign it with the same file you have used for creating the API key(debug.keystore). Keep this in mind !

Answer (score 2):

You may be run your code in newer system. For that you need to get new API key using the new **SHA1** from the console.

Orelse,

Follow the process,

1. Go to the home of your older system
2. Find the location ---- `/.android/debug.keystore`
3. Copy the `debug.keystore`
4. Replace the `debug.keystore` in your newer system
5. Your map will be working fine.

Advance wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just move your code to another machine and expect it to work.
As been mentioned already you Google Map uses an API key that was produces using the SHA1 fingerprint from the debug.keystore folder in your user folder.

In order this to work you have 2 choices:

**1.** Copy the the debug.keystore to the other machine you want to develop this project on.

**2.** Register the SHA1 fingerprint from the new machine into the console as well.

Comment: I deleted a key from google console and created a one from another machine. Still it did not work. And now it stopped working on my machine, too. I tried creating keys thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the keyhash from the other machine to your Google API Console account?